# Sharepoint External Data - multi value field

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, bdc

I need to create a list field which contains external datas (from BDC). The field has to contain multiple values. But I didn't found a way how to make a external-data-field taking multiple values.

Creating such a multivaluefield from User-Contetntype is possible by using the Column-Properties. By creating a column from external data I do not have the possibility to activate multi-value mode.

It should look like this, just from a external data source (BDC):
[image]

Does anyone know how handle such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

What TypeName is your TyperDescriptor? Set it to an Array of a type.
Eg.

```
<TypeDescriptor Name="somename" TypeName="System.String[]" />
```

If you're changing the type of an existing crawled property, you need to delete it first.
Unmap it from all managed properties, exclude property from search index and delete on the Business Data category. Reset index and IISRESET.
Do a full crawl and your crawled property is now multivalued (Variant Type 4127).